# Ошибка при десереализации класса, наследованного от HashMap (Jackson)

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Я наследую класс `SectionHashMap` от HashMap, т.к. нужно добавить пару методов. Но при попытке десереализации возникает

`` com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.ddev.learnthewords.Dictionary$SectionHashMap` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): no default constructor found ``

хотя конструкторы имеются. Попробовал множество способов из интернета, но ничего не помогает, надеюсь на вас.

SectionHashMap (он вложенный):

```
    public class Dictionary {
    @JsonProperty("Orthoepy")
    public SectionHashMap Orthoepy = new SectionHashMap();
    @JsonProperty("Orthography")
    public SectionHashMap Orthography = new SectionHashMap();
    @JsonProperty("Paronyms")
    public SectionHashMap Paronyms = new SectionHashMap();


    public class SectionHashMap extends HashMap<String, String[]>{
        public SectionHashMap(){
            super();
        }
        public void putLower(String key, String[] values){
            String lowerKey = key.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
            ArrayList<String> lowerValues = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] arr = (String[]) lowerValues.toArray();
            for (String line:values) {
                lowerValues.add(line.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
            }
            this.put(lowerKey, (String[]) lowerValues.toArray());
        }
        public String[] getKeys(){
            return (String[]) this.keySet().toArray();
        }
    }
    @JsonCreator
    public Dictionary(@JsonProperty("Orthoepy") SectionHashMap orthoepy, @JsonProperty("Orthography") SectionHashMap orthography, @JsonProperty("Paronyms") SectionHashMap paronyms){
        super();
        this.Orthoepy = orthoepy;
        this.Orthography = orthography;
        this.Paronyms = paronyms;
    }
    public Dictionary(){
        super();
    }

}
```

ObjectMapper:

````
public static Dictionary JsonToDictionary(String json){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Dictionary dictionary;
    try {
        dictionary = mapper.readValue(json, Dictionary.class);
        return dictionary;
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;
}```
````

Comment: У вложенных не статических классов при компиляции генерируется параметр конструктора для передачи ссылки на объект внешнего класса (чтобы обеспечить доступ к его членам), поэтому в рантайме у них нет дефолтного конструктора. Сделайте его статическим, а лучше перенесите в отдельный класс-файл

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением было перенести SectionHashMap в отдельный файл